# Silverlight for windows embedded

Tags: c++, xaml, windows-ce, silverlight-embedded

This is my xaml file.

```
<UserControl
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
x:Class="SilverlightApplication1.Page"
Width="640" Height="480" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" mc:Ignorable="d" xmlns:vsm="clr-namespace:System.Windows;assembly=System.Windows">
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="ButtonStyle1" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Grid>
                        <vsm:VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <vsm:VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                                <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Unfocused"/>
                                <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Focused"/>
                            </vsm:VisualStateGroup>
                            <vsm:VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <vsm:VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Duration="00:00:00.0010000" Storyboard.TargetName="image" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)">
                                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="1.207"/>
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Duration="00:00:00.0010000" Storyboard.TargetName="image" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)">
                                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="1.207"/>
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Duration="00:00:00.0010000" Storyboard.TargetName="image" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.X)">
                                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="15.5"/>
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Duration="00:00:00.0010000" Storyboard.TargetName="image" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.Y)">
                                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="17.877"/>
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </vsm:VisualState>
                                <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Duration="00:00:00.0010000" Storyboard.TargetName="image" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)">
                                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="0.567"/>
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Duration="00:00:00.0010000" Storyboard.TargetName="image" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)">
                                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="0.567"/>
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Duration="00:00:00.0010000" Storyboard.TargetName="image" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.X)">
                                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="-32.5"/>
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Duration="00:00:00.0010000" Storyboard.TargetName="image" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.Y)">
                                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="-37.483"/>
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </vsm:VisualState>
                                <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Disabled"/>
                            </vsm:VisualStateGroup>
                        </vsm:VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Image Source="bounce_media.png" Stretch="Fill" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" x:Name="image">
                            <Image.RenderTransform>
                                <TransformGroup>
                                    <ScaleTransform/>
                                    <SkewTransform/>
                                    <RotateTransform/>
                                    <TranslateTransform/>
                                </TransformGroup>
                            </Image.RenderTransform>
                        </Image>
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="ButtonStyle2" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Grid>
                        <vsm:VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <vsm:VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                                <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Unfocused"/>
                                <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Focused"/>
                            </vsm:VisualStateGroup>
                            <vsm:VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <vsm:VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Duration="00:00:00.0010000" Storyboard.TargetName="image" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)">
                                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="1.243"/>
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Duration="00:00:00.0010000" Storyboard.TargetName="image" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)">
                                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="1.243"/>
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Duration="00:00:00.0010000" Storyboard.TargetName="image" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.X)">
                                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="18.208"/>
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Duration="00:00:00.0010000" Storyboard.TargetName="image" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.Y)">
                                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="21"/>
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </vsm:VisualState>
                                <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Duration="00:00:00.0010000" Storyboard.TargetName="image" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)">
                                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="0.6"/>
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Duration="00:00:00.0010000" Storyboard.TargetName="image" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)">
                                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="0.6"/>
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Duration="00:00:00.0010000" Storyboard.TargetName="image" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.X)">
                                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="-30"/>
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Duration="00:00:00.0010000" Storyboard.TargetName="image" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.Y)">
                                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="-34.6"/>
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </vsm:VisualState>
                                <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Disabled"/>
                            </vsm:VisualStateGroup>
                        </vsm:VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Image Source="bounce_photo.png" Stretch="Fill" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" x:Name="image">
                            <Image.RenderTransform>
                                <TransformGroup>
                                    <ScaleTransform/>
                                    <SkewTransform/>
                                    <RotateTransform/>
                                    <TranslateTransform/>
                                </TransformGroup>
                            </Image.RenderTransform>
                        </Image>
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="pink">
    <Button Height="173" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="8,0,0,18" Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle1}" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="150" Content=""/>
    <Button Height="173" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,35,18" Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle2}" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="150" Content=""/>       

</Grid>
```

**The above mentioned is an xaml file built using Microsoft Expression Blend 2**

I have to use this xaml file as resource in my sub project using visual studio(c++). For this i have to develop a c++ code. But i am very unfamiliar with this technology and i need some guidance to obtain the task.

> Please also tell me where can i learn
>   to develop a c++ code for this xaml
>   file. I have heard that silverlight
>   has its own API's which is entirely
>   different from the WIN32 API's. I am
>   familiar using WIN32 API's but 
>   unfamiliar with this 
>   Silverlight Technology.

Please guide me the step or the tutorial site where i can learn the following concepts:

```
1. c++ coding in visual studio for SWE where xaml file is added as resource in 
my sub project.
```

for ex:- How to write a c++ code for windows embedded for an xaml file which will display images 
which acts as a button in the emulator ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Build a project in VS200X for Silverlight Embedded](http://shaihi.blogspot.com/2009/10/embedded-silverlight-for-windows-ce-60.html)

Answer (score 1):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee503558.aspx

Answer (score 1):

hi
you can refer the following links to know about silverlight for windows embedded this will support only native code(C++)

http://geekswithblogs.net/WindowsEmbeddedCookbook/archive/2009/10/01/silverlight-for-embedded-tutorial.aspx

http://aimidas.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!4585C53D5F64E56B!1479.entry
you can convert your xaml file into c++ file using XAML2CPP you can get it from the  following link

http://cid-9b7b0aefe3514dc5.skydrive.live.com/self.aspx/.Public/XAML2CPP.zip

after you can create project using win32 smart device project by using Visual studio