# How to add Silverlight in Windows CE 6.0?

Tags: silverlight, windows-ce, silverlight-embedded

I want to add Silverlight in my win ce . Can anybody tell how to add the Silverlight application?
And what are the thing I want to add in the catalog menu. Please tell me the steps for this.

Comment: i already installed Win ce R3 and am having that demo file . pls tel how to add. bec i created a new sub project and build.but i cant able to add the demo file wat u told.

Can u tell me what are the steps to do that.

Vinoth.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You first need to install [Windows CE 6 R3](https://web.archive.org/web/20100803041105/http://www.microsoft.com:80/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=BC247D88-DDB6-4D4A-A595-8EEE3556FE46&displaylang=en) (look at the **Required Software** section to understand the installation order - it is *critical*).

You need to look for `XAML` in the catalog and add those items that suite you. Mainly, you need `SYSGEN_XAML_RUNTIME`. Now you just need to do a `Sysgen` and you have Embedded Silverlight included.

To include the sample you need to add `SYSGEN_SAMPLEXAMLPERF`. It is not in the catalog so add it through a batch file or in a command-line build window. (You can read more [here](https://discovertheexperience.blogspot.com/2009/10/windows-embedded-ce-60-r3-silverlight.html))

You can read [Silverlight for Windows Embedded tutorial](https://web.archive.org/web/20210122073003/http://geekswithblogs.net/WindowsEmbeddedCookbook/archive/2009/10/01/silverlight-for-embedded-tutorial.aspx) for a tutorial on a Embedded Silverlight application. This post explains how to add an Embedded Silverlight subproject to a current OSDesign.

Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2727152/silverlight-for-windows-embedded/2801100#2801100) for instructions to setup a project without Platform Builder. If you follow these instructions you can setup the same project that is described in the above tutorial, but use a regular smart device project without platform builder.

Comment: The tutorial link ist dead, here ist the updated link: https://web.archive.org/web/20170509114625/geekswithblogs.net/WindowsEmbeddedCookbook/archive/2009/10/01/silverlight-for-embedded-tutorial.aspx